# Why does Acrobat not see LaTeX (pdflatex) generated form fields?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, pdftex

I used the [hyperref](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) package and pdflatex to make a nice PDF form. The form works fine in that I can fill out the fields and save the contents.

However, I want to make a fancy field that performs a calculation on the values of some other fields. I can do this in Acrobat without problems, by changing the properties of one of the pdflatex generated form fields to calculate a sum.

So far so good! However, when I try to "distribute" my updated form (with the calculation) Acrobat claims there are no fields in the document. However, Acrobat itself lists a bunch of fields. (See the screenshots below.) What do I have to do to get Acrobat to save the document with the form calculation correctly? If I use File > Save, the calculation does not get saved.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36630/hyperref-how-to-format-text-in-a-forms-text-field/40360#40360