# pdftex and javascript forms with automatic calculations

Tags: pdftex, forms, javascript

I would like to create a PDF document in TeX with a form.  Some of the fields in the form will be calculated based on the values of other fields.

Here is a MWE, thanks to [Victor Ivrii on the pdftex mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2006-June/006644.html) back in 2005:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[maxlen=40,keystroke={AFNumber_Keystroke(2, 0, 1, 2,
true);},align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=alpha]{Alpha}

\bigskip
\TextField[maxlen=40,keystroke={AFNumber_Keystroke(2, 0, 1, 2,
true);},align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=beta]{Beta}


\bigskip
\TextField[maxlen=40,keystroke={AFNumber_Keystroke(2, 0, 1, 2, true);},
calculate={AFSimple_Calculate("SUM" , new Array ( "alpha" , "beta" )
;)},  align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=gamma,readonly=true]{Gamma}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF has three fields, and the third is supposed to automatically update to be the sum of the first two.  If I compile the document and open in Acrobat, I can edit the first two fields (`alpha` and `beta`) but the third (`gamma`) does not update.  No JavaScript errors are thrown.

If I examine the properties of the field `gamma` in Acrobat, I can see that its `calculate` property is set to be the sum of the to fields `alpha` and `beta`.

[image: Acrobat window and dialog]

If I select "Pick...", I'm shown a dialog with the three fields, and `alpha` and `beta` are selected.  If I deselect and *reselect* those fields and accept, the form now works as desired ([Acrobat-altered document at scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/109720332/Ivrii-Fixed)).  The `diff` command tells me the PDF file has changed but not how.

I have found some discussion about this on the pdftex mailing list, in the above referenced thread and again [here](http://osdir.com/ml/tex.pdftex/2005-08/msg00014.html).  Ralf Uterman apparently posted a [patch](http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/~ralfu/pdf-forms/) as a result of the second thread, but as far as I can tell the issue persists.  I have tried the `eforms`  package from the [AcroTeX bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex) as well, but the author writes in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/eformman.pdf) that "Calculate works correctly when drivers `dvips`, `dvipsone`, or `dvipdfm` are used." (`pdftex` is not listed).

Yet I cannot get this to work under any driver.  If I use the `dvips` driver to compile to DVI, then `dvips` to convert to PostScript, then convert to PDF using either Acrobat Distiller, I get the same non-functioning form as with `pdftex`.  If I use the `dvipdf` driver, then `dvipdf` to convert to PDF, all the form elements are unrecognized and ignored.

This document is going to be stamped over a scanned PDF so I really need no other output except the form and some basic marks.  So I'm flexible as to engine, driver, etc., but so far I'm not getting anything to work without manual intervention via Acrobat.  I'm aware of the related question “ [hyperref: how to format text in a forms text-field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36630/hyperref-how-to-format-text-in-a-forms-text-field/40360#40360) ” but I can't get the calculations to work in the accepted answer there, either.

Comment: Can you give a link to a correct PDF file (after modification by Acrobat)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Sure.  http://www.scribd.com/doc/109720332/Ivrii-Fixed (also added to question)

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your file: `scribd.com` requires registration to allow download! But it does not matter since you have a good answer below.

Comment: @Paul: sorry, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Package `hyperref` 2012/10/12 v6.83i now implements the missing calculation order array in the `/Form` dictionary for the three driver classes that support PDF forms (pdftex, dvipdfm/xetex, pdfmark/dvips). If a field element contains calculation code, then this field element is automatically added to the calculation order array. Currently only document order is supported.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}[2012/10/12]

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[maxlen=40,align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=alpha]{Alpha}

\bigskip
\TextField[maxlen=40,align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=beta]{Beta}

\bigskip
\TextField[
  maxlen=40,
  calculate={%
    var f_alpha = this.getField("alpha");
    var f_beta = this.getField("beta");
    event.value = f_alpha.value + f_beta.value;
  },
   align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=gamma,readonly=true]{Gamma}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

### Update

Since `hyperref` 2012/10/13 v6.83j the calculation order can be specified, if
pdfTeX is used, from `README`:

> ### Field option `calculatesortkey`
>
> Fields with calculated values are calculated in document order
>   by default. If calculated field values depend on other calculated
>   fields that appear later in the document, then the correct calculation
>   order can be specified with option `calculatesortkey`. Its value is
>   used as key to lexicographically sort the calculated fields.
>   The sort key do not need to be unique. Fields that share the same
>   key are sorted in document order.
>
> Currently the field option `calculatesortkey` is only supported by
>   the driver for pdfTeX.

Comment: Updating packages just for answering questions and get the rep is cheating. `;-)` I'm very happy that you're able to support so many features.

Comment: TeX.SeX really helps the TeX grow quickly.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 This field is automatically calculated. That is the point of the exercise.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 From the question "the third is supposed to automatically update to be the sum of the first two". And the JavaScript calculation is a simple sum: `event.value = f_alpha.value + f_beta.value;`

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Evince does not support JavaScript.

Comment: How can you have predeclared values there in the form of checkboxes? My thread about it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384286/how-to-compute-two-checkbox-values-of-form-and-present-on-adobe

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 There is option `value` for the fields.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek How do you apply `value` there?

Answer (score 17):

The [PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) requires that every form field that should be recalculated must be registered in the *calculation order* entry of the interactive form dicitionary (cf. pp. 416, 431). [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) doesn't do this automatically though, so your JavaScript isn't taken into account by the viewer. The [patch you mentioned](http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/~ralfu/pdf-forms/) should take up this job, but it doesn't seem to work any more, probably because the `hyperref` implementation has changed: With the current version, the default form dictionary without the calculation order is used instead of the "correct" one as created by the patch.

This solution adds form fields with a non-empty `calculate` value to the calculation order (automatically). The implementation is very similar to the creation of the list of all form fields as done by `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\HyField@calcorder\ltx@empty
\Hy@AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \string\providecommand\string\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder[1]{}%
    }%
  \fi
  \def\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder#1{%
    \xdef\HyField@calcorder{%
      \ifx\HyField@calcorder\@empty
      \else
        \HyField@calcorder
        \space
      \fi
      #1 0 R%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\HyField@@AddToFields#1{%
  \HyField@AfterAuxOpen{%
    \if@filesw
      \write\@mainaux{%
        \string\HyField@AuxAddToFields{#1}%
      }%
      \ifx\Fld@calculate@code\@empty
      \else
        \write\@mainaux{%
          \string\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder{#1}%
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}%
\patchcmd{\@Form}{/Fields[\HyField@afields]}{/CO[\HyField@calcorder]/Fields[\HyField@afields]}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[maxlen=40,keystroke={AFNumber_Keystroke(2, 0, 1, 2,
true);},align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=alpha]{Alpha}

\bigskip
\TextField[maxlen=40,keystroke={AFNumber_Keystroke(2, 0, 1, 2,
true);},align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=beta]{Beta}


\bigskip
\TextField[maxlen=40,keystroke={AFNumber_Keystroke(2, 0, 1, 2, true);},
calculate={AFSimple_Calculate("SUM" , new Array ( "alpha" , "beta" )
);},  align=2,height=10pt,width=45pt,name=gamma,readonly=true]{Gamma}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: form fields with auto-calculated value]

BTW: In your MWE, the `;` in the `calculate` expression was misplaced, this is corrected in the above code.

---

The [`eforms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package requires `hyperref`, but it implements the creation of the form fields differently, so the above patch won't work. However, it can be adapted by patching the text field macro of `eforms` to call the auxiliary `hyperref` command necessary for generating the calculation order. This code should work for text fields created both by `hyperref` and `eforms`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\HyField@calcorder\ltx@empty
\Hy@AtBeginDocument{
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \string\providecommand\string\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder[1]{}%
    }%
  \fi
  \def\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder#1{%
    \xdef\HyField@calcorder{%
      \ifx\HyField@calcorder\@empty
      \else
        \HyField@calcorder
        \space
      \fi
      #1 0 R%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\HyField@@AddToFields#1{%
  \HyField@AfterAuxOpen{%
    \if@filesw
      \write\@mainaux{%
        \string\HyField@AuxAddToFields{#1}%
      }%
      \ifx\Fld@calculate@code\@empty
        \ifisCalculate
          \write\@mainaux{%
            \string\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder{#1}%
          }%
        \fi
      \else
        \write\@mainaux{%
          \string\HyField@AuxAddToCalculationOrder{#1}%
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}%
\patchcmd{\@Form}{/Fields[\HyField@afields]}{/CO[\HyField@calcorder]/Fields[\HyField@afields]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\eq@TextField}{\hbox{\pdfstartlink user{\common@TextFieldCode}%
\lower\eqcenterWidget\ef@Bbox{\eq@rectW}{\eq@rectH}\pdfendlink}}{\hbox{\pdfstartlink user{\common@TextFieldCode}%
    \lower\eqcenterWidget\ef@Bbox{\eq@rectW}{\eq@rectH}\pdfendlink}\HyField@AddToFields}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{20pt}}rl}
Number 1: & \textField[\AA{%
    \AAKeystroke{AFNumber_Keystroke(1,1,0,0,"",true)}
    \AAFormat{AFNumber_Format(1,1,0,0,"",true)}}]{num.1}{1in}{11bp} \\[6pt]
%
Number 2: & \textField[\AA{%
    \AAKeystroke{AFNumber_Keystroke(1,1,0,0,"",true)}
    \AAFormat{AFNumber_Format(1,1,0,0,"",true)}}]{num.2}{1in}{11bp}\\[6pt]
%
Total:    & \textField[\AA{%
    \AAKeystroke{AFNumber_Keystroke(1,1,0,0,"",true)}
    \AAFormat{AFNumber_Format(1,1,0,0,"",true)}
    \AACalculate{AFSimple_Calculate("SUM", new Array("num"))}
}]{totalNum}{1in}{11bp}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: auto-calculated form fields with eforms]

Comment: Works for the example!  I'll have to check if it works in my more complicated case.  But I hope its as simple as this.

Comment: Nuts.  Doesn't work in my actual use case.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I've updated my answer to add only the form fields to the calculation order that should actually be recalculated - maybe this can solve your problem?

Comment: it might be the `eforms` package that is undoing the work of your patch.  So far it works with each of my trials that uses `hyperref` only, and none of the ones that use `eforms`.  Thanks for working on this.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang `eforms` generates the forms field differently, so the patched commands weren't used for form fields generated with the `eforms`-specific macros. I've enhanced the patch in order to (hopefully) support `eforms`.

Comment: Thanks again!  I'll have the chance to test your patch on a real-life example this week.  As for the check/bounty, I felt like I had to award it to Heiko since he went to the trouble of updating the package.  I might ask a separate question related to `eforms` for you.

Comment: Is there any update for the approach here? I hope the situation has improved since 2012. My application of checkboxes here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384286/13173