# Create fillable pdfs that can do calculations

Tags: pdf, calculations

I am interested in create a fillable PDF, for which I found [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs) question which tells to use hyperref. But I am curious that if I have 2 number fields, A and B, and I want a third field to be a number field, but not where you write, but where it gives the result A+B. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the calculate-option for a textbox in hyperref, which requires a JavaScript code. There is a solution in the following question, where there's also a discussion on a problem that can occur and its solution.

[pdftex and javascript forms with automatic calculations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75981/pdftex-and-javascript-forms-with-automatic-calculations)