# Calculations in TextField do not work

Tags: hyperref, forms, javascript

I want to have some TextFields in my form where one can put numbers (shares) and the last TextField should be 100 - the sum of all other TextFields.
I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75981/pdftex-and-javascript-forms-with-automatic-calculations) but it did not help, nothing happens. I do not know where the problem is.

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{makecell,
  tabularx}           
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\subsection{Welchen Anteil in \% (geschätzt) haben folgende Bereiche:}

\begin{itemize}[itemsep=4pt]

\item \TextField[name = anteilquali]{Qualitätsmanagement:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteildaten]{Datenschutz:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteilorga]{Organisation:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteilfinanzen]{Finanzen:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteiloeffentlich]{Öffentlichkeitsarbeit:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteilsonstige, readonly = true, calculate={%
    event.value = 100 - 
    (this.getField("anteilquali").value +
    this.getField("anteildaten").value + 
    this.getField("anteilorga").value + 
    this.getField("anteilfinanzen").value + 
    this.getField("anteiloeffentlich").value); 
  }]{Sonstiges:}

\end{itemize}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` turns double-quotes into active characters which blow up the JavaScript code embedded in the PDF output. If they are replaced with single quotes, `'`, the code remains intact. Also, it might be useful to provide the text fields with initial values:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{makecell,
  tabularx}           
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\subsection{Welchen Anteil in \% (geschätzt) haben folgende Bereiche:}

\begin{itemize}[itemsep=4pt]

\item \TextField[name = anteilquali,value=0]{Qualitätsmanagement:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteildaten,value=0]{Datenschutz:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteilorga,value=0]{Organisation:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteilfinanzen,value=0]{Finanzen:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteiloeffentlich,value=0]{Öffentlichkeitsarbeit:}\\
\item \TextField[name = anteilsonstige,value=100,readonly = true,calculate={%
    event.value=100 - (
    this.getField('anteilquali').value + 
    this.getField('anteildaten').value +  
    this.getField('anteilorga').value +  
    this.getField('anteilfinanzen').value +  
    this.getField('anteiloeffentlich').value); 
  }]{Sonstiges:}

\end{itemize}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much!