# How can I change font in pdf forms?

Tags: fonts, pdf, cyrillic, forms

I'm making a pdf form with "hyperref" package:

```
\usepackage[unicode,pdftex,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true,pdfauthor={Author},pdfkeywords={some words},
    pdftitle={some title},pdfborder={0 0 0}
    }
\def\dflt{print,borderwidth=0,bordercolor={1 1 1},charsize=14pt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofPushButton{\dflt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofCheckBox{radiosymbol=\noexpand\ding{52},\dflt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofText{\dflt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofListBox{\dflt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofComboBox{edit,sort,\dflt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofPopdownBox{\dflt}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofRadio{radiosymbol=\noexpand\ding{52},notoggletooff,\dflt}

\begin{document}

\section{\LaTeX forms}
\subsection{Information:}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=sname,width=3cm]{First name:}
\TextField[name=fname,width=3cm,borderwidth=0]{Last name:},
…
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Both in latex with utf8x and in xelatex with "Liberation Serif" I get wrong results: text in forms is something like "Sans" and it is obviously differs from other text.

**Q1**: can I change font properties to make forms looks like other text?

**Q2**: I have troubles with cyrillic in both evince and okular, in acroread all OK, but this is not good to compel people to install it instead of their usual pdf-reader. Is it possible to create such forms with cyrillic, that would be fillable in okular or evince?

Comment: I cannot help you with the second question, but for the first one take a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36630/hyperref-how-to-format-text-in-a-forms-text-field

Comment: @DominikusK., no, such method gives the same ugly result.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think this will get answered as it doesn't really show us how the fonts get loaded and that makes it hard to test out. I'm therefore closing as 'unclear', but will reopen once an edit is made: flag when appropriate.