# Embed complete fonts (not subsetted) in XeLaTeX PDF

Tags: fonts, xetex, embedding

I have an application that requires the use of PDFs with fonts completely embedded. The source is a simple TeX file:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Warnock Pro}

\begin{document}

\centering

\hbox to 7in{%
    \$[Jobname]%
    \hfill
    \$[Sig]%
    \hfill
    \$[SL]%
    \hfill
    \$[Color]%
    \hfill
    \$[OutputComment]%
    \hfill
    \$[Date]%
}

\end{document}
```

The fonts in the resulting PDF are have been subsetted. Based on a question ([Embedding a complete rather than a partial font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140303/embedding-a-complete-rather-than-a-partial-font)) which received no answer, I tried fiddling with dvipdfmx.cfg to no effect by using:

```
D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v 
    -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode 
    -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode 
        -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100
    -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"
```

I made sure that I was editing the correct file with:

```
kpsewhich -progname=dvipdfmx -format='other text files' dvipdfmx.cfg
```

Can this be done?

Comment: That was contained in the link to which I referred in my query, which, as I pointed out, had no answer. Been there, done that.