# Forms not working with cyrillic

Tags: hyperref, cyrillic, forms

[This guy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107478/how-can-i-change-font-in-pdf-forms) had a similar problem as me. Text fields simply refuse to accept cyrillic input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}     % For coloured rows within tables.
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Hide section and page numbers.
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[bordercolor=black, width=8cm, height=5cm, charsize=10pt, value=стойност]{\tiny Външен вид}  \\
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

The form refuses to render both initial or hand-entered value. I am using `evince`.

How can I fix this so that all pdf viewers are supported?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan nothing changes. Would it be helpful if I  compose a minimal-er example? With that option included.

Comment: It's a poppler bug: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/463