# Form: How to change the font into TextFields globally

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe, javascript

I would like to have typewriter-font into my pdf-form.

So I find out the mechanism

```
\TextField[width=5cm, name=NAME,value=Font manually changed,
format = { var f = this.getField('NAME'); f.textFont = 'Courier'; }, 
]{B: }
```

depending on the `name` of the textfield.

I can do this smarter using a corresponding command, but I ask myself: 
*Is there a possibility to set the font globally for all textfields?*

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

% Gobal Styles
\def\Default{
print, bordercolor=red,backgroundcolor=lightgray,borderstyle={U},
}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofText{\Default}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[width=5cm, name=a,value=Default Font]{A: }
\TextField[width=5cm, name=b,value=Font manually changed,
format = { var f = this.getField('b'); f.textFont = 'Courier'; }, 
]{B: }

Let's do this with a newcommand:

% \TEXTFIELD[<opt. Arg.>]{<name>}{<title>}
\newcommand{\TEXTFIELD}[3][]{%%
\TextField[width=5cm,
name = #2,  
format = { var f = this.getField('#2'); f.textFont = 'Courier'; }, 
#1, 
]{#3}
}%%

\bigskip
\TEXTFIELD[value={Font changed}]{C}{C:}
\TEXTFIELD[value={Font changed too}]{D}{D:}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

% Global Styles
\def\DefaultOptionsofText{
 print, bordercolor=red,backgroundcolor=lightgray,borderstyle={U},
 format = {var me = event.target.name;  
          var f = this.getField(me); 
          f.textFont = 'Courier'; }}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[width=5cm, name=a,value=Default Font]{A: }
\TextField[width=5cm, name=b,value=Font manually changed,
]{B: }
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer You are a Turbo Woman! :()

Comment: But as I recall @UlrikeFischer this is not going to work reliably beyond the compiler's own computer. Unless the full fonts are embedded (which is hard to achieve?) or the viewer has the font installed locally it will not work and will be worse than using an always-available system font (which will be unpredictable).

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Ok, I think, I understand. I thought, "Courier" is usually available in Win or Linux systems. What could a  "always-available system font" be?  

BTW: Are there any fonts that AdobeReader ships with by default? AdobeReader is, to my knowledge, a mandatory prerequisite for this type of form.

Comment: Yes you may be relatively (not completely) safe with a few fonts (Palatino
Garamond, Bookman, courier..). Many pdf readers other than AdobeReader can open/process forms. But my point was more general - you will not be able to select any random font and think that you will have a system independent product (in contrast to fonts outside the form which can be embedded regardless of whether they exist on the system). Adobe Reader does contain some fonts which do not need to be embedded (courier being the only fixed point one afaik).

Comment: FWIW, this works on Acrobat on mac os, but fails for Preview.app and Skim.app