# Change the default font for textfield (Hyperref)

Tags: hyperref

So, I'm trying to make a fillable pdf using latex Hyperref package.
While the process works for what I intend to do, I can't find any way to change the font of the Textfield.

I tried the following code, from [Form: How to change the font into TextFields globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469010/form-how-to-change-the-font-into-textfields-globally), but my text still shows up as Arial, and I need it to be CMR8 (Already installed in both MiKTex and on a local instance). Below is an image showing up what's happening. I've tried doing it in both Vs Code and Overleaf, thinking it was a problem with my installation at first.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please add a MWE of what you tried so far.

Comment: As the comments under my answer say,  controlling the font is hard. You can find a few more details in the documentation of l3pdffield-textfield (in pdfmanagement-testphase)