# Fillable PDF form autoscaling font size

Tags: hyperref, pdf, fontsize

I want to create a pdf with several fillable form boxes but I can't do so with any free PDF software.  I can do it in LaTeX but I can't seem to figure out how to get the text in the fillable form to scale its font size to fit.  I found the code below and I can make the box whatever size I like, but any text I type inside the box remains a set size and doesn't scale to fit like other PDFs I've seen.  I couldn't find anything about it in the hyperref documentation, is there any way to do this or am I SOL?

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\TextField[name=multilinetextbox, multiline=true, width=\linewidth,height=5in]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No scaling, but you could set the font size manually: `\charsize = 12pt`. ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40360/269505))

Answer (score 1):

As far I got your query, you want something like this?

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\TextField[name=multilinetextbox, multiline=true, width=\linewidth,height=5in,charsize=30pt]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I have just added a piece of option param: `charsize=30pt`. See the code.

Comment: Not quite, if the text in this box gets too long it will add a scrollbar.  I want the text's fontsize to scale down instead of adding a scrollbar.

Comment: @Will Be I have never seen this in a pdf and I doubt, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible. C. f. [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-to-make-an-expanding-text-field-in-acrobat-pro/m-p/8254204) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056724/expandable-text-fields-in-pdf-forms-with-adobe-acrobat). In addition, I presume that you have seen not a text field expansion, but rather a **shrinking of the font size**, if a scrollbar would be needed. At least this happened to me recently. But I do not know how to do it with hyperref.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the charsize to 0pt. Then the font will adjust if you add more text. This is part of the pdf specififation:

> A zero value for size means that the font
> shall be auto-sized

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\TextField[name=multilinetextbox,multiline,charsize=0pt,
width=\linewidth,height=1in]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]